# Hide field after checking if user is admin - deferred promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to hide a field from a newform, but only if the user is not a site collection administrator and not assigned full control of the (sub)web currently on. I am not well experienced in JavaScript/jQuery, but I hoping I am on the right path. I am on a Sharepoint 2013 on-premise environment.

The main thought here was that I check if a user is site collection administrator first - if so set the global var isSiteAdmin to true, same goes for check on subweb. If both of these return false, the field is hidden.

However, when the script runs I always get false on these two variables when running the function hideSiteManagerField(), even though I am both site administrator and have full control on web. It seems as if the checks aren't ready when that function is firing, but in the console I see that my messages are showing (the console.log ones in code below).

This might be because of the async nature of the requests I am thinking. To ensure I have run the functions isUserSiteAdmin() and isUserWebAdmin() before running the last function that hides the field, I had this notion that I could use the deferred method in jQuery? Being a novice at this I do not know if I am using it correctly? If not could someone please help me?

Also - is there a better/safer/cleaner way to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', readyFunction);
});

var isSiteAdmin = false;
var isWebAdmin = false;
var context;
var web;

function readyFunction() {
    $.when(isUserSiteAdmin(), isUserWebAdmin()).done(hideSiteManagerField)   
}

function isUserSiteAdmin() {
  return $.Deferred(function () {
    var currentSite = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
    var currentUserID = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    $.ajax({
        url: currentSite + "/_api/web/siteUsers?$select=Id,IsSiteAdmin&$filter=id eq " + currentUserID,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item1) {
                isSiteAdmin = item1.IsSiteAdmin;
                console.log("User is admin on site: " + item1.IsSiteAdmin)
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    })
})
}

//If a user is admin he/she will have manageWeb permissions.
function isUserWebAdmin() {
  return $.Deferred(function () {
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    context.load(web, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');
    context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);

    function onSuccess() {
        if (web.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has(SP.PermissionKind.manageWeb)) {
            isWebAdmin = true;
            console.log("User is admin on web: true");
        }
    }
    function onFailure(sender, args) {
        alert('failed: ' + args.get_message() + 'n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
})
}

function hideSiteManagerField() {
//hide field Site Manager if permissions != full access or administator on site collection
if (!isSiteAdmin && !isWebAdmin) {
    $('div[title="SiteManager"]').parents().eq(2).hide()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working version of your code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', readyFunction);
});

var isSiteAdmin = false;
var isWebAdmin = false;
var context;
var web;

function readyFunction() {
    $.when(isUserSiteAdmin(), isUserWebAdmin()).done(hideSiteManagerField)
}

function isUserSiteAdmin() {
    var currentSite = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
    var currentUserID = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

    return $.ajax({
        url: currentSite + "/_api/web/siteUsers?$select=Id,IsSiteAdmin&$filter=id eq " + currentUserID,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item1) {
                isSiteAdmin = item1.IsSiteAdmin;
                console.log("User is admin on site: " + item1.IsSiteAdmin)
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    })
}

//If a user is admin he/she will have manageWeb permissions.
function isUserWebAdmin() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(function () {
        context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = context.get_web();
        context.load(web, 'EffectiveBasePermissions');
        context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);

        function onSuccess() {
            if (web.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has(SP.PermissionKind.manageWeb)) {
                isWebAdmin = true;
                console.log("User is admin on web: true");
                deferred.resolve();
            }
        }

        function onFailure(sender, args) {
            alert('failed: ' + args.get_message() + 'n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}

function hideSiteManagerField() {
    //hide field Site Manager if permissions != full access or administator on site collection
    if (!isSiteAdmin && !isWebAdmin) {
        $('div[title="SiteManager"]').parents().eq(2).hide()
    }
}
```

The `hideSiteManagerField` will be called only when the deferred objects returned by `isUserSiteAdmin` and `isUserWebAdmin` are both resolved. But in your code, you didn't call `$.Deferred().resolve()`.

In `isUserSiteAdmin`, I removed `$.Deferred`, you can return `$.ajax` directly. It is deferred compatible. The internal jQuery code will call `resolve` for you.

In `isUserWebAdmin`, I created a Deferred object first, then add `deferred.resolve()` in the `onSuccess` callback and at last it returns `deferred.promise()`. (You can attach callbacks to promise object as deferred object, but you cannot call `resolve` or `reject` on a promise object, so it ensures that the state of the deferred object will not be changed outside your function).

Comment: Thank you for your help with this and for useful comments. I was not aware you could return $.ajax directly like that. Good to know!

Comment: @user3463093 I'm glad it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I always use this regarding deferreds, sure there will be a better looking way but it always works for me:

```
function fxRun() {
    Step1().then(Step2);
}
```

With:

```
function Step1() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            //your code here to determine isWebAdmin
            dfd.resolve()
        }, 2000);
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}

function Step2() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            //your code here 
            dfd.resolve()
        }, 2000);
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}
```